# Fill missing rows in a python pandas dataframe using similar rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, missing-data

Suppose I have this kind of Dataframe:

```
Data:   Lat    Long   Postal Code
    0   41     32     01556
    1   32     31     01023
    2   31     33     01023
    3   NaN    NaN    01023
    4   33     42     01775
    5   40     44     01999
```

As you can see, rows 1,2,3 have the same postal code. So, in order to fill the NaNs, it would be nice to just use the average of those 2 rows (1,2).
How can I generalize this for a large dataset?

- For each row with NaN data in Lat/Long,

  - Find other rows with the same postal code
  - then compute the mean
  - and use it to replace the NaNs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

`groupby`, `transform`, `fillna()`

We first select a slice of our dataframe and use `fillna` to only fill missing values, we don't want to overwrite any of the existing data.

we then leverage the `groupby` function to group by postal codes as you requested.

we use the `transform` method which returns your data with its original index and length.

we assign this to your columns and have the result as below.

```
   df[["Lat", "Long"]] = df[["Lat", "Long"]].fillna(
    df.groupby("Postal Code")["Lat", "Long"].transform("mean"))
    print(df)
          Data   Lat  Long  Postal Code
    0     0  41.0  32.0         1556
    1     1  32.0  31.0         1023
    2     2  31.0  33.0         1023
    3     3  31.5  32.0         1023
    4     4  33.0  42.0         1775
    5     5  40.0  44.0         1999
```

Comment: I've tested the code with even more NaNs, works like a charm! This is so damn nice, baraka allahu fik!